# Remove portion of string TSQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a string of numbers that I need to trim a portion from using TSQL.

The string of numbers will always start with a 101 then it will have a set of 0's and a set of random numbers.

Example: `1010000123456`

I need to trim the 101 and the set of zeros. This is probably simple but I'm having all kinds of issues because I don't have a specific character to reference to using a CHARINDEX and the possible combination of a 001 when the random numbers start that I need to keep is giving me issues using a PATINDEX with a SUBSTRING.

Comment: Are these values guaranteed to be numbers only? If so you could just remove the first 3 and cast the remainder as an int. That would remove the leading 0s easily

Comment: Do you always know the number of zero's?

Comment: `1010000123456 - 1010000000000 = 123456` ?

Comment: Something simple like this work? select cast(RIGHT('1010000123456', len('1010000123456') - 3) as int). If you have any characters other than numbers this will not work. It would also not work if the numbers are all 0s after the initial 101

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 101 in the string, Cast to big integer and then cast back to string.

```
select cast(cast(right('1010000123456', len('1010000123456')-3) as bigint) as varchar(20))
select cast(cast(right('1010000103456', len('1010000103456')-3) as bigint) as varchar(20))
```